# Finding which points are above or below threshold created with smooth.spline in R

Tags: r, plot, points, threshold

I'm working with a big dataset and had modelled the null distribution based on a subset of this big dataset. Now I have two thresholds, one upper and one lower thresholds, which are represented in a plot with `smooth.lines` function. I want to add all the points that are in original big dataset and pick up only those that falls above the upper threshold or the lower one.

I saw some questions that are related to this issue, but not really helped me.

The two smooth.splines are shown below with code used to generate it:
[image: The two smooth.splines are shown below with code used to generate it.]]

```
null=read.table('./FLK/FLK_missing25/envelope_missing25.txt',head=T)
attach(null) 
plot(Ht,q0.005,xlim=c(0,0.5),ylim=c(0,80),type='l',col='gray',xlab='Heterozygosity',ylab='FLK statistic')
lines(smooth.spline(Ht,q0.995))
lines(smooth.spline(Ht,q0.005))
detach()
```

And after plotting all the original points to it:
[image: Points added to plot]

```
points<-points(tests$Ht,tests$F.LK,pch=16, cex = 0.3)
```

So now I want to specifically choose those that are out of the bounds. In a previously, small dataset I manually did it using the identify() function, but now it's not viable.

Thank you for any help with this.

Sample of the data:

NULL DATA

```
    Ht q0.005 q0.995
0.00591439962121213 0.0470479532111184 2.50113629965976
0.0152043356973995 0.903847984179369 5.27712913495654
0.0247475329218107 1.10641288480299 8.38474123256296
0.0347981812865497 1.79379631237697 9.79551961929076
0.0447457820512821 1.50091253935435 13.5764489968702
0.0545112254521964 1.701442607667 14.716108081672
0.0647035527065527 1.8777834231014 19.7193011141249
0.0752057147315855 2.02703289299316 22.4056042334654
0.0853695647249191 2.55886670448224 26.3526825156905
0.0951034362745098 2.32581254159768 26.8590094714685
0.105249967013889 1.97512544742914 33.1975332778596
0.114477015605493 2.97238131961918 36.1521540009195
0.124979204031465 3.34075814389952 37.2515434121372
0.134785529320988 3.34714566225456 32.2932733505792
0.14490944879227 3.10226576305214 29.8338494464933
0.15506127420999 4.24950042259053 27.4185967884072
0.165180424133811 3.99191672611036 26.9666648107656
0.175250313459801 4.14044881633145 23.7361745813858
0.184953524875622 3.3261251322879 24.8595451578181
0.195661799033816 3.8585956628444 26.9607468892232
0.205136950292398 4.52812897956441 27.706304158175
0.21514489063867 4.47365964145688 28.3733660157821
0.224770744698897 3.46185120833234 23.3146767700615
0.235134508838384 4.20860691006497 25.2703736048277
0.245463810699588 5.25816733914855 24.4633123881128
0.254697365555556 5.01608789493179 22.436360164922
0.265263011937557 5.41045366008221 21.234603036848
0.274965869230769 4.57547849203251 22.123537129909
0.284762001736111 4.96960407757807 23.1453940270167
0.295016995780591 5.03463125959773 23.8167819631306
0.304919664888889 4.91088844199837 31.1948521499049
0.315003866394001 5.38422627088829 24.5116307178719
0.324648699845679 4.65914520212904 21.3910532375308
0.335376895143488 4.72500998773501 21.0712548679782
0.345309140503876 3.65292271944213 19.481764437033
0.355141738580247 4.87361431797648 19.7086186354089
0.36492435045045 3.3720338431453 21.1623708350575
0.374838788499025 4.42750819261774 22.4270755627995
0.384949760401371 6.32843488472143 19.4328206516264
0.394694700377562 6.13747955626477 21.0407091272595
0.405097673087661 5.92323768549744 20.0022002025301
0.415122219310036 7.04730509921557 19.838320586508
0.425285395264117 5.26585166530237 19.2312352201651
0.434997939814815 6.81458009465107 18.5690310892543
0.445171238970588 6.38590526021563 19.7545747503063
0.455201864718615 6.80826318124284 20.7346637551957
0.465409469306323 6.69008793893291 18.916645338847
0.475095361731458 6.82480379491385 19.2349327044628
0.485306814387211 6.4417087151098 19.1705016428993
0.496692359771218 6.50900360561522 18.5886408042256
```

SAMPLES OF 400 POINTS:

```
Ht F.LK
0.124444444444444 36.7500584428158
0.0349234567901235 7.68626952677946
0.095 13.9121809485979
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.316651234567901 18.1680720158939
0.0165277777777778 4.44427163440377
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.124444444444444 22.7267096656174
0.375 15.3610576981023
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.408027160493827 11.1592362583977
0.0327777777777778 4.82380608461891
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0644444444444444 19.0408956498371
0 0
0.0176197530864198 4.04842613535931
0.04875 6.38514116317343
0.0644444444444444 9.08082795264823
0.0219753086419753 2.77731149495652
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.095 12.4833417013004
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0798611111111111 7.28613317182042
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.21875 17.1896129695331
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0219753086419753 3.21314807835817
0.132108641975309 18.556113446321
0.18 14.2995388389357
0.424382716049383 14.8425335909128
0 0
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.0327777777777778 4.85098786477187
0 0
0.0852997448979592 9.0349481226104
0.0373696145124717 3.50183528527322
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0.235439231824417 13.7995627381987
0 0
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0592438271604938 5.21774915912316
0 0
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.293061111111111 16.517027637416
0.148132716049383 14.3827251495301
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0849382716049383 19.6029386110943
0.39875 16.1698547005385
0.0132444444444444 3.3468904905399
0.0176197530864198 1.99690131691949
0.231111111111111 15.8361807587094
0.0434567901234568 6.40317107162842
0.258321995464853 16.1388383746647
0.0540123456790123 3.33523979403527
0.357777777777778 11.1009117328169
0.0644444444444444 9.72417962592817
0.0219753086419753 2.77731149495652
0.0327777777777778 4.8730619342236
0.0188662131519274 3.74952974929918
0.39875 19.6484754339051
0.339024417009602 16.3175265727668
0.124444444444444 23.3688865292886
0.0889777777777778 24.0226912089526
0.36995 14.8376551579362
0.0349234567901235 4.61414555275328
0.124444444444444 37.1525030700281
0 0
0.0849382716049383 24.0788597825384
0.0849382716049383 7.07229178174128
0.095 27.2056400197924
0.42 14.9657549617429
0.04875 7.32934570263806
0.0165277777777778 4.18793116296522
0.124444444444444 22.7267096656174
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.455 16.2644703184679
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.406111111111111 14.9554868719022
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0219753086419753 3.63621960105724
0.0190458579881657 3.44986705436526
0.04875 6.804404278778
0.124444444444444 22.7267096656174
0.0798611111111111 11.6322074035758
0.0327777777777778 9.32483341411409
0.04875 7.4146254695531
0.0234227709190672 3.05975064289059
0.316426886145405 15.5636064013468
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.0176197530864198 2.25323038510266
0.124444444444444 29.8469556711493
0.104938271604938 6.76940759330798
0.143456790123457 13.5781524622378
0.0747530864197531 5.37493552245388
0.0132444444444444 3.3468904905399
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.483194444444444 15.0706194040885
0.0165277777777778 4.39209176720576
0.274058641975309 16.5756978747446
0.0327777777777778 4.85098786477187
0.295910493827161 13.6609425469527
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0132444444444444 3.3468904905399
0.04875 6.804404278778
0.0176197530864198 2.28360196351557
0.0349234567901235 3.1531925641648
0.0014803840877915 0.208488814916637
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.0349234567901235 4.2171295869503
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0327777777777778 9.43857115397289
0.132108641975309 21.5018400019892
0.0219753086419753 3.21831506149061
0.472777777777778 11.3832414981619
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.0644444444444444 18.8204554463659
0.104938271604938 16.6202701829041
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.124444444444444 19.3579825254014
0.0176197530864198 4.10328828108007
0.0219753086419753 3.21314807835817
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0462836762688615 10.8871162342715
0.0327777777777778 4.20181588220052
0.119808 28.0423119358955
0.141577777777778 10.3947265408058
0.0849382716049383 13.6388393237215
0.0219753086419753 3.63621960105724
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.095 13.9121809485979
0.0798611111111111 22.7814003533669
0.0434567901234568 6.40317107162842
0 0
0 0
0.04875 7.4146254695531
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.124444444444444 20.8970552010047
0.04875 13.3436423633028
0.0327777777777778 4.20181588220052
0.0165277777777778 4.44427163440377
0.451604938271605 14.2580434675109
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.04875 6.38514116317343
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.388503086419753 12.024032362231
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.104938271604938 17.3933460851521
0.489795918367347 2.6885312137628
0 0
0.449861111111111 17.8013216714898
0.0798611111111111 8.12520300770917
0.0165277777777778 4.39209176720576
0.143456790123457 9.55416885361777
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.49395 17.2286473899574
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0434567901234568 7.33110895561598
0.109861111111111 8.49079906480581
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.0644444444444444 8.62632335592837
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.487021604938272 13.2551758042932
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.095 27.2056400197924
0.124444444444444 15.6712952124286
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.309861111111111 16.0122904428983
0.0644444444444444 8.18561561753904
0.274058641975309 12.0694901513446
0.32 16.4164943866946
0.193194444444444 14.7250995621834
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.0219753086419753 5.59353033970332
0.0327777777777778 8.94350852495432
0 0
0.124444444444444 20.2019151572928
0.277777777777778 13.4006745238862
0.464444444444444 11.0681987513934
0.0219753086419753 3.21831506149061
0.0165277777777778 4.44427163440377
0.495 11.7232625589786
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0 0
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0 0
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0.0798611111111111 22.5255266189454
0.193194444444444 11.4014772624059
0.0132444444444444 3.3468904905399
0.0327777777777778 4.82380608461891
0.04875 3.56314021068146
0.0462836762688615 5.82756031662101
0.357777777777778 14.0247153884293
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0 0
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.493194444444444 10.504634730485
0.0434567901234568 6.5593607362431
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.0327777777777778 4.82380608461891
0.0732879818594104 7.57979262928242
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.255 11.6765957622922
0.0176197530864198 2.30009872451987
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.0644444444444444 9.89453455906778
0.266527777777778 13.6197851546911
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.100977777777778 27.5711004179377
0.0644444444444444 18.8204554463659
0.0327777777777778 8.41931161938731
0.193194444444444 16.6198637338073
0.193194444444444 19.7385825307107
0.0434567901234568 7.33110895561598
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0434567901234568 6.5593607362431
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0392 10.1241813815794
0.0327777777777778 8.94350852495432
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.206111111111111 10.7701153093882
0.0165277777777778 4.39209176720576
0.231111111111111 15.8361807587094
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.0327777777777778 4.82380608461891
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.095 27.2056400197924
0.0219753086419753 3.63621960105724
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0 0
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0 0
0.0219753086419753 5.86839006118109
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.13875 8.83478779181092
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0327777777777778 4.20181588220052
0.0219753086419753 3.18871230960838
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.451604938271605 10.3016606110791
0.428641975308642 14.1709573991617
0.0798611111111111 22.7814003533669
0.04875 7.32934570263806
0.0519111111111111 7.18588289074698
0.0327777777777778 4.8730619342236
0 0
0.326604938271605 13.6925832569272
0.0644444444444444 10.0302939975709
0.0132444444444444 3.3468904905399
0 0
0.0327777777777778 4.48012764852979
0.0644444444444444 4.25757204398404
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0 0
0.124444444444444 11.8966041620809
0.0176197530864198 2.24670145143038
0.302947530864198 15.647557284147
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.472777777777778 21.6545151604864
0.0219753086419753 2.96231029591765
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.104938271604938 14.9037953666261
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.124444444444444 38.7541517402647
0.095 14.140401856445
0.13875 22.2923964937516
0.458271604938272 11.4277070501224
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.197530864197531 11.9942366204454
0.391111111111111 19.9433036596453
0.0644444444444444 8.62632335592837
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.0014803840877915 0.19386782953831
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.18 13.0718970161537
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0644444444444444 10.0302939975709
0.0644444444444444 8.18561561753904
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.0327777777777778 4.85098786477187
0.0644444444444444 17.9052407023711
0 0
0.0176197530864198 4.27297510503453
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0 0
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.0219753086419753 4.79410958577714
0.095 12.4833417013004
0.0849382716049383 14.9026698258922
0 0
0.18 14.1143183366686
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.124444444444444 18.9544262421443
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.124444444444444 19.3579825254014
0.095 13.9121809485979
0.095 28.8112723065338
0.109861111111111 11.6589142293783
0.0165277777777778 2.21267921892221
0.124444444444444 22.7267096656174
0.0644444444444444 9.90058337915599
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.0165277777777778 4.64135741279412
0.095 7.61134574637366
0.406111111111111 11.774577707447
0.0519111111111111 6.99859311140469
0.04875 7.32934570263806
0.493194444444444 15.3312617641375
0 0
0.495 14.9338542232795
0.18 13.2478860417367
0.0165277777777778 4.44427163440377
0.0165277777777778 4.44427163440377
0.0219753086419753 6.27439399313949
0.124444444444444 18.2181906541074
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0798611111111111 11.6322074035758
0.0327777777777778 4.82380608461891
0.0462836762688615 6.18972392803396
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0 0
0.0165277777777778 2.40249815554879
0.0519111111111111 3.17830618816259
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0.0219753086419753 3.18871230960838
0.0644444444444444 9.08082795264822
0 0
0.0327777777777778 4.02670803483571
0 0
0.24399012345679 17.8565540311217
0.095 15.1423376148871
0.499938271604938 16.1602588277824
0.35265306122449 13.7374609889186
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.0327777777777778 4.48012764852979
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.46141975308642 12.3837914568937
0.0219753086419753 3.16274375984679
0.277777777777778 13.9541603218533
0.118644444444444 8.51767581949589
0.0219753086419753 5.86839006118109
0.04875 7.4146254695531
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0 0
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.0165277777777778 4.69907933357134
0.302249382716049 17.6464696415598
0.124444444444444 16.9269546015968
0 0
0.0176197530864198 4.27068975182888
0.0327777777777778 4.20181588220052
0.476527777777778 17.9889760853764
0.0327777777777778 4.85098786477187
0.0165277777777778 2.40211994735022
0.0327777777777778 4.20181588220052
0.04875 6.804404278778
0.0234227709190672 3.04032675868852
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.0434567901234568 6.40317107162842
0.0165277777777778 2.07413566780096
0.494429012345679 11.7189833713657
0.0165277777777778 2.38147829746204
0.255 18.3064046174448
0.24399012345679 14.1721617969582
0.391111111111111 12.0438089335106
0.383194444444445 12.6438502507037
0.04875 7.4146254695531
0.124444444444444 22.7267096656174
0.496527777777778 13.1939316331812
0.366527777777778 19.4450595714789
0.124444444444444 37.1525030700281
0 0
0.0327777777777778 4.4474073979159
0.0327777777777778 4.48012764852979
0.0462836762688615 11.3471579553117
0.48875 17.0368364232462
```

PS.: I improved the null model and now it's much more accurate.

PS.2: Added the values of upper and lower bounds and a small sample of points as suggested. Sorry if it become too long.

Answer (score 0):

`smooth.spline` saves a list you can merge with your data:

```
ssH <- smooth.spline(null$Ht, null$q0.995)
ssL <- smooth.spline(null$Ht, null$q0.005)
tests <- merge(tests, data.frame(Ht = ssH$x, F.LK0.995 = ssH$y), by = "Ht")
tests <- merge(tests, data.frame(Ht = ssL$x, F.LK0.005 = ssL$y), by = "Ht")
```

Then `tests[tests$F.LK > tests$F.LK0.0995 | tests$F.LK < tests$F.LK0.005, ]` are out of bounds

P.S. don't use attach - detach and null is a terrible data name

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working. The result shows 0 lines. To clarify, I guess that a ")" is missing after 'data.frame(Ht = ssH$x, F.LK0.995 = ssH$y', right? Another issue that I think is that this data.frame has 50 lines and the tests has 17989. But I liked you're rationale. Trying to follow your method. If I make it run I post here.

Comment: I fixed the parentheses and another reference to null.  It's my impression that null$Ht would have only the unique Ht values from tests.  If that's the case, this should work.  This would be much easier if you would provide a small sample of the data.